# jquery .load with python flask

Tags: jquery, python, html, flask

I am trying to use jquery .load in my flask app to add a div every time the user presses a button to add a new div, but it can't find the html file.

The function in question.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add").click(function(){
            $("#form").load('/templates/info.html');
        })
});
```

The info.html file only hold a short div section of html.

index.html the code, where I want to load the info.html div after the form.

```
  <form id="form" action="{{ url_for('get_data') }}" method="post">
        <input type="button" name="add" value="Add" id="add">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="To XML">
    </form>
```

/templates/info.html

```
 <div id="info">
     <label>name</label>
     <input type="text" name="name">
     <br>
     <label>asfd</label>
     <input type="text" name="asfd">
      <br>
 </div>
```

I keep getting this 404 error.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2014 19:55:50] "GET /templates/info.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I am running the flask app locally, and /template/info.html is the correct path. I just don't know why it doesn't load in that html.  I am able to make it work when I use the jquery function and .append() and put the long html string into the append function, but add the info.html gets longer I just want to be able to load the whole file.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: `templates` is just a folder. Flask doesn't serve the contents unless you explicitly ask it to. Setup a route (`@route('/info')` or something similar), render the template, and request `/info` instead of that URL.

Comment: But won't jquery look in the template folder, and load the html file?

Comment: Folders are for file systems. jQuery sends a GET request to the webserver and requests the resource at `/templates/info.html`. From there, it's entirely up to Flask to determine what `/templates/info.html` actually means. It could just send back the URL in reverse as a response. Flask doesn't serve the contents of `/templates/` the same way it does for `/static/`, which might be a better choice for you (although I would suggest instead to make a route that actually renders the template, as in the below answer, and use jQuery to load it).

Comment: I edited my question I think I understand what you are saying, but I don't know if that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Then just drop it into `/static/` instead of `/templates/`.

Comment: That worked, but now I can only press the add button once, any reason for that?

Answer (score 7):

Your view definition within the flask app should return the info.html. In other words, you should have a route and a method in your flask application as:

```
@app.route('/info')
def info(name):
    return render_template('info.html')
```

Now in your jquery code you can load the url `/info`. Flask by default looks for templates in the templates folder, so no need to explicitly mention that in the URL

Comment: It worked for me! Just what I was looking for. Thanks so much!